# From a jar file, calling the main method from a class that implements a class from outside the jar

Tags: java, jar, program-entry-point

Suppose I have a jar file called 'MyJar.jar' with a class defined like this:

```
import SomeInterface;

public class MyClass implements SomeInterface {
   static public void main ( String args[] ) {
     ...
   }
}
```

Note, however, that the interface 'SomeInterface' is NOT in the jar file.  Instead its referenced in another jar file called 'SomeJar.jar'

My manifest-mf file does include something like this:

```
Main-Class: MyClass
```

Now, assume that I try to run the 'main' method on this 'MyClass' class from my jar file using what seems like workable syntax, i.e.:

```
java -cp SomeJar.jar -jar MyJar.jar
```

In this case, I get something like:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MyClass
```

However, if I rework the syntax like this, everything works fine:

```
java -cp SomeJar.jar;MyJar.jar MyClass
```

For a sanity check, I did do the former call with a 'HelloWorld' class with an appropriate manifest file entry and that worked.   It seems that this problem only occurs when the class in question implements an interface that isn't immediately available to the jar file, but instead exists outside of it.  (This might happen for exending a class as well, but I haven't checked)  As you can see, I can make things work... just not with the 'java -jar' syntax that I thought would work.  Additionally, with the former way, I DO NOT get a "NoClassDefFoundError" error (which I thought I would), regardless of whether I include the "-cp" classpath in the "java -jar" call or not.

Any thoughts why the former "java -jar" call does not work (and does not seem to give any good errors on WHY its not working) and yet the latter "java" call works fine?

Answer (score 1):

The `-cp` and `-jar` options both set (rather than append to) the underlying classpath.  Whichever option is on the command-line last will override all former `-cp` and `-jar` options.

Comment: Interesting.  So "-jar" is only useful if EVERYTHING can exist in the single JAR file and/or one feels ok adding outside classpaths to the manifest (even though those classpaths may change if the JAR is deployed to a different environment).  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Yes, that's generally right.  The other popular option is to put minimal logic in your single JAR to programmatically compute a full classpath and create a class loader.  That's the approach used by most large/extensible applications (Eclipse, application servers, etc.).